# HTML5 chart stacked bars with repeated colors

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, chart.js

I want to plot bars composed of a small but variable number of colored regions, with the same (three) colors appearing multiple times per bar. I'm aware of [stacked bar charts in chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/stacked.html), but this uses the same number of colored regions (datasets) for each bar. Hacking it to plot a bunch of zero-length datasets to get the right number of colored regions in each bar feels wrong. That said, the tooltips, etc. in chart.js are nice, so if there's no more natural solution, maybe zero-length datasets are the way to go. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

So, instead of using chart.js, I think I'll use [d3.js](https://d3js.org/). Won't be hard to just plot the individual rectangles using d3.

For reference, an example that only has one bar per entry, but won't be hard to extend is the [horizontal barplot shown here](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_horizontal.html). (There's a [simple intro to d3.js](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/intro_d3js.html) on the same site.)